# Not supported error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a method that accepts a date `dtSince` and a string `component` as parameters. I need to write an one-line linq query that searches for entries that occurred before `dtSince` and is of Component `component` (if specified). I have tried the following:

```
var result = from items in MyAzureTable
             where items.Occured >= dtSince
             && items.Component == (component ?? items.Component)
             select items;
```

But I'm getting a NotSupported error. I guess the `items.Component == (component ?? items.Component)` is the problem.

As mentioned, `component` can be null or empty. But I cannot exclude that in the original query, because this:

```
var result = from items in MyAzureTable
             where items.Occured >= dtSince
             select items;
```

might return more than 1000 rows (which appears to be the default limit of Azure tables) and therefore I cannot filter it with the `component` later. If I do something like the below, the entry I might be looking for is at row 1001. Thus, it won't give me the result I am looking for.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(component))
{
    result = result.Where(x => x.Component == component).ToList<>();
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to have a one line linq query that can check for a non-empty string first before using it in a where clause?

Comment: Does azure really not provide an `IQueryable<T>` API? I would expect the `where` to "compose"...

Comment: @Marc, There appears to be a limit of queryable rows in Azure Tables. This guy is trying to query 200 million, and see what happened. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837213/azure-querying-200-million-entities

Comment: @Alex - but that is different; by *composing* a query you should be filtering *before* the query goes to the server, so the final query won't (or shouldn't) perform the open query

Comment: That'll work too, but it sounds like a little more complex than the one-liner I was looking for. Correct me if I'm wrong, or if you have a sample, that'd be great. Thanks

Comment: @Alex it *should* work as per your sample, as long as you aren't calling `ToList()` higher up, which it doesn't look like you are. What is confusing, though, is your use of `ToList()` which suggests (because the assignment works) that `result` is a `List<T>`. Indeed that would *NOT* compose. So; is the actual problem here that you have (in your real code) a `.ToList()` too high up?

Comment: @Marc, Alas, I have a `ToList()` somewhere in between. Let me try without that and see what happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = from items in MyAzureTable
             where items.Occured >= dtSince && 
                   (component == null || items.Component == component)
             select items;
```